# one to many relation (laravel and mysql)

Tags: mysql, laravel, many-to-many

I need help with this situation:

I have Player class ( id, name, level, email)

one player will have to field one form like this:
9h-11h.  11h-13h.   13h-15h.  (etc..)
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday

I want that the player select his availability for every day
Example:
9h-11h.  11h-13h.   13h-15h.  (etc..)
Monday.     x.                  x
Tuesday
Wednesday             x
Thursday.   x.        x.        x
Friday
Saturday
Sunday

How can i save this data into database ?
BEcause if i search for monday between 9h-11 the result will be all the palyers who select that option.

I'm trying to do it with mysql and laravel

Help please

Comment: Single player can save multiple availability each day ? or a single availability each day ? However this is not many to many, its `one-to-many`.

Comment: Single player may have multiple

Comment: @LeilaOliveira Yeah, that's correct. A single player has Many. That is a `hasMany` not a `belongsToMany`. A many-to-many means: A lot of players have several hours, and the hours have many players. @AkhzarJaved is right.

Comment: thanks both. but @AkhzarJaved  I'm still confused how should i save this data into database. could you help ?

Comment: depends how you want to model it - are you doing Player - Availability (Monday + times, Tuesday + times) - or Player, Days, Availability, what do your other models look like ?

Comment: @futureweb so far I have 3 models (player, day, hour) but i'm not sure what's the best practice for this case.

Answer (score 0):

if a player can have many days and a day can have many hours and a day can also have many players and an hour can have many players sounds like you need some sort of pivot between players - days and hours something like:

```
Schema::create('day_hour', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('day_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('hour_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('player_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['day_id','hour_id','player_id'], 'day_hour_id');
    });
```

then in Player:

```
public function days(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class, 'day_hour');
}

public function hours(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hour::class, 'day_hour');
}
```

Same in Day:

```
public function players(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class, 'day_hour');
}

public function hours(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Hour::class, 'day_hour');
}
```

Same in Hour:

```
public function players(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Player::class, 'day_hour');
}

public function days(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Day::class, 'day_hour');
}
```

You could also probably use a polymorphic relationship https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations